# Limit points of $x_{n+1}=2\cos(x_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems

Here is a question I am not able to answer.

> Find the limit points of the iterative sequence given by $x_0=2$ and
>   $x_{n+1}=2\cos(x_n)$

If one relaces $2\cos$ by $\cos$ then it is a classical exercise and the sequence converges. Here $x_n$ s bounded so has limit values which form a compact set $A \subset [-2,2]$. Numerical simulations suggest that there exists $a,b,c>0$ such that $A=[-a,b] \cup [c,2]$. But I am not able to prove it.

Well the only thing I can tell is that the $y$ such that $2\cos (y)=y$ is such that $2\sin (y) >1$ and thus there is a region around $y$ which can not contain any limit value.

Comment: You can solve for potential candidates if you solve for $x_n = 2 * cos(x_n)$. You need to prove that it actually converges to that value. You can do this by applying Banach.

Comment: I think that you are mistaken: it is pretty obvious that this sequence does not converge. Also remark that the initial condition is very important. You have to start from a point $x_0$ such that $x_1 \neq y$ (with my notation).

Comment: Oh yeah maybe you are right. My bad

Comment: $f(x)=2\cos(x)$ fixed point is unstable, but you can consider iterative $f(f(x))$ and then get $3$ fixed points some of which are attractive now.

Comment: Well, that's a start. But I really think the limiting values are indeed a union of two intervals. Is there a general theory for iterative maps? Some reference book?

Comment: However that is a good remark: simulations confirm that $a_n:=2\cos(2\cos(a_n))$ with $a_0:=2$ should be dense in $[c,2]$ for $c \approx 1.3$